# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nnext'

Tags: python, linked-list, attributeerror

I am trying to remove the last node from a linked list, I made the `temp` variable and made it store the head to iterate over the list, but the line:  `while(temp.nnext != self.tail):` is giving me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nnext'`. How can I fix it?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data,nnext=None):
        self.data=data
        self.nnext=nnext

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
         self.head=None
         self.tail=None

    def removelast(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return None
        if self.head == self.tail:
            return self.removefirst()
        temp=self.head
        while(temp.nnext != self.tail): #this line here
            temp=temp.nnext
        tail=temp
        temp=temp.nnext
        tail.nnext=None
        return temp.data
```

Comment: Could you also provide some dummy data?

Comment: by avoiding that `temp` is `None` in the first place. Debug your code with a debugger or some prints (never used a python debugger in 13 years using it!)

Comment: At some point, the `nnext` in `temp=temp.nnext` is `None`, so the next time you loop through, `temp` is `None`, so then you attempt to get `None.nnext`, which produces your error. Your code doesn't expect `nnext` to ever be `None`, so either you need to check for `None`, or figure out why that's being set to `None` in the first place if you don't expect it to ever be set to that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you assign to `tail`, creating a new variable. But you don't alter `self.tail`, which means the *second* time you call this function, the `while` condition will never be true. Instead `temp` runs to the end of the list without encountering `self.tail` and `temp` becomes `None`.

So change:

```
tail=temp  # This creates a new variable
temp=temp.nnext
tail.nnext=None  # This mutates the variable, but not the linked list
```

to:

```
self.tail=temp
temp=temp.nnext
self.tail.nnext=None
```

Comment: Could you give some feed-back to this answer?